# Git merge ignores new files and certain changes in other existing files

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree

The current situation in my Git repository is as follows:

1. I pulled "master" from the remote into my local master. My local master is now up to date with the remote.
2. I have a local branch called "feature" that I want to merge master into (i.e **from** master into "feature"), so I can keep working on the feature with some recent necessary changes that were merged into "master" from other branches. The master has some files that don't exist in "feature", and some changes in files that do exist in "feature".
3. When trying to merge, the new files aren't being added to the branch and some of the changes in the existing files are also being ignored (i.e they don't get merged automatically and they don't appear as conflicts that need manual resolving).
4. I tried: `git merge master`, `git rebase master`, and also merging via the "Sourcetree" GUI tool.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"they don't get merged automatically and they don't appear as conflicts that need manual resolving"_ - this says to me that the merge didn't happen? Please may you add the git commands used and the output that git provided? (if you didn't use the command line, try it with that first)

Comment: I did:
`git checkout master`

`git pull origin master` (master is now up to date with remote)

`git checkout <feature>`

`git merge master` / `git rebase master` (I tried both)

Now, the merge sort-of happens because some files do get merged automatically and others do have conflicts that I can manually resolve, which is great. But some don't and I have no idea why even though there are definitely differences. Also, there's the files that exist on master but not on the branch which don't get added to the branch.

Comment: Just to clarify. `rebase` is not merging so you may not see the result you initially intended. Using `git merge` _will merge the branches_ (usually by creating a merge commit), but without more information it's hard to say what's "going wrong".

Comment: Unfortunately that's all the information I have, I clearly see files in my local master that don't get added to my branch when I run `git merge master` in my local branch.

Comment: There could be many reasons why they're not there? One reason could even be that you removed them from your branch at some point.

Comment: Did you *complete* the merge? If you have conflicts, after you resolve them, you must `git merge --continue` (or your UI may have a continue button).

Comment: Well they never were on my branch. I created the branch before they existed. They were added in another branch which was merged into master after my current branch was created.

Comment: And if you rebase (which is usually my preference under normal circumstances), you also have to continue it if you have conflicts (`git rebase --continue`)

Comment: Well I aborted the merge (`git reset --hard`) when I saw that some files weren't being merged, so no.
Same with rebasing.

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: I would try completing (either the merge or rebase) to see if the files show up. You can always `git reset --hard` back to the commit you were on before the merge/rebase if you are unhappy with the result.

Comment: Status output:
`On branch <feature>
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)`
The list of "Changes to be committed" lists some new files, but not all. One specific file that has changes that need merging doesn't appear there, nor in the list of "Unmerged paths".

Comment: Well, `git merge --continue` didn't help.

Comment: To clarify, when you checkout `master` you see a (new) specific file you are interested in. And then after you checkout your branch `feature` it is gone (as expected), and after `git merge master`, resolving conflicts, and continuing, you still don't see the file you are interested in? If yes, is the new file on `master` the same as another new file on your branch?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and no, the new file on `master` doesn't have a similar file in my branch.

Comment: _"You have unmerged paths"_ so the merge hasn't finished. Run `git commit` or `git merge --abort`

Comment: Yes, correct, the merge hasn't finished because there are conflicts that I need to resolve, but even after I resolve them and complete the merge, I don't see the files new files, or the changes to some of the existing files.

Comment: OK. I'm at "that's strange". If a co-worker asked me this we'd do a call and a screen share and have it solved in a few minutes. Without that option though, you could try to mimic a rebase manually to see what's going on. To do this, make a new branch off of `master`. Now cherry-pick each of the (new) commits from your branch one by one (in the order you created them). After one of the cherry-picks, if the files disappear, you'll know that something about that specific commit and/or your conflict resolution is what caused it. If they don't disappear after you're finished, then problem solved!

Comment: Just a thought... any chance you already merged `master` into your branch after the file was added to `master` and that merge commit removed it? You can test this by identifying the commit on `master` where the file was added. Then run `git merge-base master feature` and look at the commit it spits out. If that commit ID comes after the commit ID on `master` where the file was added, then you have a bad merge on your branch already.

Comment: I don't think `master` was merged into my branch previously, but it's possible that I forgot. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: OK so apparently `git checkout --patch master <path to problematic file>` works! Now my problem is that I don't know if there are some problematic files that I didn't notice un till now, it's a pretty huge project.